# Date argument as view filter

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm using Drupal 6.

I have a custom view that needs to be filtered by an argument passed by the user.

The argument is a simple date, and I need my query to be filtered like the following:

```
WHERE created >= %argument&
```

Where %argument% is the user argument passed within the URL.

The thing is, I manage to filter it, but only as equals, like this:

```
WHERE created = %argument&
```

Is there any way I can make it filter as `greater or equal to`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Drupal 6 views dont support such feature.

The solution was to implement the `module_views_query_substitutions` hook and alter the query manually:

```
function module_views_query_substitutions($view)
{
    $view->query->where[0]['clauses'][3] =
        str_replace('=', '>=', $view->query->where[0]['clauses'][3]);
}
```